# Using GeoServer REST API and C# to create Layer Group

Tags: geoserver, c#, rest, api

Following information at this [link](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/restconfig/rest-config-examples/rest-config-examples-curl.html) in the section on creation of layer groups, I've created the method(C#):

```
public bool AddToLayerGroup(string layerGroupName, string layerName)
        {
            try
            {
                string gUrl = GEOSERVER_HOST + "/rest/layergroups";
                WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(gUrl);

                request.ContentType = "application/xml";
                request.Method = "POST";
                request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(GEOSERVER_USER, GEOSERVER_PASSWD);

                byte[] buffer = Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8").GetBytes(GetAddToLayerGroupXml(layerGroupName, layerName));
                Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
                requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                requestStream.Close();

                WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

When I run a unit test against this method, I get an `Internal Server Error` reported from GeoServer if I use `POST` HTTP method.

Now the `layerGroupName` and `layerName` used in the above method are already existing in GeoServer. What I want to achieve is provide a way to create a layer group if it doesn't exist, or just use an existing one. The `layerName` always already exists in GeoServer, as I'm using a separate method to create them.

Can anyone spot any problem with my code above. Or, suggest an alternative approach. cURL or Java or C# examples are welcome. Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:
From Tomcat logs, GeoServer complains that the layer group I've specified already exists. Is there away to add a layer to an existing layer group using the REST API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A POST will always create a new resource and redirect you to it once created.
If you want to either create a new one or replace an existing one you must use PUT instead.
Mind, it will overwrite fully an existing layer group (btw, haven't tried it out, the above is just based on what you should expect from a REST based API).

Comment: Thanks, @Andrea, for the swift response. I don't wish to replace an existing layer group; I just want to reuse it. Is there away to reuse a layer group without affecting the layers it already has?

Comment: You have to get its representation using GET, add the new layer into it, and then PUT it back. You cannot modify it.